# Does query multiple indices slower than querying single index in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a retention index which is used to save transaction data. The index pattern in on yearly, which means `transaction-2000`, `transaction-2001`, etc. There is a `timestamp` field inside each document which indicate the time of this document occurred.

I also have an alias `transaction` which points to all yearly transaction indices. When I query the transaction data in my application, I just use the alias name rather than the yearly index name.

My question is if I query just one year document based on the `timestamp` field, e.g. `2000`, will the query be faster if I only query the single index `transaction-2000` rather than the alias `transaction`? Or whether they are the same speed?

Answer (score 0):

Joey , this is a classic elasticsearch problem. When you have multiple aliases behind an alias , all of them are queried. One way to overcome this is to use routing which comes in extremely handy if you already know which index to go to. At query time if you already know the ts field (2000 or 2000 and 2001 for example) , you can specifically instruct to search only 2 indexes behind the alias using the route

https://www.elastic.co/blog/customizing-your-document-routing

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-shard-routing.html

We had a similar issue when we scaled for a large DataSet search (similar design where multiple indexes were behind an alias) , routing came in handy and the queries scaled to our requirements. Hope this helps